# What's the function of the image description?

Tags: support, images

What's the function of the image description?

When we ask a question, and if we upload an image, there will be a default description place:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ykzB.jpg
```

I don't know the `![enter image description here]` function there. Sometimes I fill it in, but there is nothing more in the question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526791/when-is-it-acceptable-to-leave-the-alt-text-empty-on-an-html-image-if-ever/23526792

Comment: I assume its for the cases of when the picture isn't posted into the question as that's the text in the link

Comment: I'm tempted to flag as off-topic for Meta since this is just a question about standard Markdown. =)

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144080/299295).

Comment: Seemingly, to be left as the default by most users... :(

Comment: @Shadow That's not true; a good number of users manage to replace it with the first half of the following sentence, apparently in order to make the puzzle of figuring out what they're asking more challenging, and therefore more rewarding.

Comment: Heh I stand corrected, @abarnert. I've certainly seen evidence of both scenarios.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The "enter image description here" is used to fill the [alt text](https://html.com/attributes/img-alt/#The_alt_text) of the inserted image. While this text isn't shown if the image loads normally, it is useful in several cases:

- For users of assistive technology (particularly screen readers) so that they can still get the gist of the image's purpose despite not being able to see the image.
- If the image fails to load for some reason or is blocked (sometimes corporate proxies block the Stack Imgur in particular), the alt text will be shown instead.

You can block images in your browser if you want to see what effect the alt text has. If you're able to provide a relatively short but accurate description of the image, you should try to do that in order to help anyone who can't see the image.

You can also see the [Markdown Basics](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) page on Daring Fireball where it shows what the image format does:

```
![alt text][id]

[id]: /path/to/img.jpg "Title"
```

Note that Stack Exchange automatically wraps the image in a link so that you can click to expand it.

Comment: For completeness: the Markdown inserted when clicking the Insert Image button in the editor includes a link to the image. There is no postprocessing in place that adds links to all images in posts automatically.

Comment: That alt text is also used by search engines to help index images/pages.

Answer (score 9):

The text `enter image description here` is meant to be replaced by an appropriate value for the `alt` attribute of the `img` element that adds the image to the page. The `alt` attribute is read out by [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) to blind users and by other text-to-speech software (e.g. programs used by people with dyslexia).

Compare the markdown syntax and the HTML source code for [this (randomly chosen) example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973620/6002174).

Providing text alternatives for images and other non-text content (including areas in image maps) is a basic accessibility technique. See [Technique H37: Using alt attributes on img elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37.html) for the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.1.

It is important that the alt text provides all the information that non-visual users need to understand what the page is about. If an `alt` attribute is too short for this (there are no hard and fast rules for when the content of an alt attribute is "too long"; some say 150 characters), you can add a more detailed description below the image. (In HTML, there are techniques that rely on [longdesc](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H45.html) or on [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/ARIA10), but these go beyond the capabilities of markdown.)